# Box-shadow over border

Tags: html, css

I have this problem where I want to have a border and a box-shadow, but the shadow must be over the border.

The box-shadow property starts when the border ends, is it possible to move it over the border?

```
.border
{       
    border: solid rgba(128,42,42,.98) 16px;
}


.img-box-shadow
{
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 20px #000000;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 20px #000000;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 20px #000000;
}
```

My HTML:

```
<img class="border img-box-shadow" src="img.png">
```

Already tried inset in my box shadow, but it didn't work!

I'm looking for this effect:

[image: border]

And I'm getting this result:

[image: shadow in border]

Comment: you want inner shadow for the outer most container ?

Comment: It's the same container, if you can look at my image here http://imgur.com/JHnbwTy you'll see that the box-shadow starts where the border ends, I want both of them starting where the image ends.

Comment: That's the most cockamamie looking css ever

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think this would be much more easily achieved with two overlayed box shadows.

Something [like this](https://jsbin.com/fecilof/edit?css,output) approaches what you're looking for:

```
box-shadow: 0 0 20px 5px #000000,
    0 0 0 16px rgba(128, 42, 42, 0.98);
```

Comment: @PabloPerez It's my pleasure! This (indirectly) inspired me to create a new technique for picture reveals (: You might [check it out](http://cssdeck.com/labs/inset-box-shadow-play), more versions coming tomorrow. Bed time for now!

Comment: Very nice man, I actually like them!!! Good night! I'm glad I could "help" you too.

Comment: [New link](https://codepen.io/ZachSaucier/pen/YzKpEo) to the picture reveal experiement

Answer (score 0):

You can try using inset and then lowering the alpha value of your border. It may not exactly be what you want, but it's close.

```
.border
{       
    border: solid rgba(128,42,42,.5) 4px;
}


.img-box-shadow
{
    -moz-box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 20px #000000;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 20px #000000;
    box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 20px #000000;
}
```

Alternate option (borrowed from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8289470/creating-a-fuzzy-border-in-css-3)). Don't use the `.border` and just use this (you can play around with pixel values):

```
.img-box-shadow
    {
        box-shadow: rgba(0,0,0,.98) 0px 0px 3px, inset rgba(0,0,0,.98) 0px -2px 3px;
    }
```

Here's a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ckk2t/1/)

Comment: Neither of those make the effect I really want, I'm looking for something like this: http://imgur.com/BBcraBt

Answer (score 0):

Seem like you want an `inset` box shadow, then you can use:

```
box-shadow: inset 0 -15px 10px -10px #444;
-moz-box-shadow: inset 0 -15px 10px -10px #444;
-webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 -15px 10px -10px #444;
```

[**Fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/w2uXv/)

Answer (score 0):

How about this one?

```
.ds-bottom {
  position:relative;
  overflow:hidden; 
  border-bottom:1px solid #ddd; 
}
.ds-bottom:before {
  content: ""; 
  position:absolute; 
  z-index: 1; 
  width:96%;  
  bottom: -10px; 
  height: 10px; 
  left: 2%; 
  border-radius: 100px / 5px; 
  box-shadow:0 0 18px rgba(0,0,0,0.6); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you have mistake in box shadow format.

```
 box-shadow: 0px 0px 20px #000000;
```

Change to

```
box-shadow: 0px 0px 20px 0 #000000;
```

*Due to the right format of Box Shadow Properties*

> box-shadow: **horizontal-length vertical-length blur-radius
>   spread-radius;**

Next, to make it works with your requirement you must wrap your image inside div. Box-shadow wont works over border.

Here's the style

```
div { 
  display:inline-block;
  padding:4px; /* Act as border width */
  background:rgba(128,42,42,.98); /* Act as border color */
}

.img-box-shadow
{
  box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 20px 0 #000000;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 20px 0 #000000;
  -moz-box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 20px 0 #000000;
}
```

And the HTML Markup

```
<div class="img-box-shadow">
<img src="http://graph.facebook.com/715380382/picture?type=large">
</div>
```

Check live demo http://jsbin.com/hex/1/edit